# How do I use requirejs together with QUnit

Tags: requirejs, qunit

At the moment I have this, taken from a blog post and the main app's original requirejs main script:

```js
require.config({

    baseUrl: 'js',

    paths: {
        domReady:       'lib/domReady',
        jquery:         'lib/jquery-1.10.2',
        bootstrap:      'lib/bootstrap',
        backbone:       'lib/backbone',
        underscore:     'lib/underscore',
        text:           'lib/text',
        raphael:        'lib/raphael',
        raphaelPlugins: 'lib/raphael.plugins',
        paper:          'lib/paper-full',
        kinetic:        'lib/kinetic-v4.6.0',
        fabric:         'lib/fabric'
    },

    shim: {

        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },

        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },

        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },

        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },

        'fabric': {
            exports: 'fabric'
        },

        'raphaelPlugins': {
            deps: ['raphael']
        },

        'router': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'bootstrap', 'text']
        }

    }

});

require([
    'tests/core.test',
    'tests/models/header.test'
], function () {
    QUnit.start();
});
```

The problem is that it only runs the first test in the array passed to it. How can I change this so that it runs them all?

Additionally, how do I make it load all of the dependencies of 'router' for each individual test?

Comment: A link to the mentioned blog post?

Comment: It's immaterial. Question includes all relevant code and what I am trying to do.

Comment: @kryger nice edit, didn't know SO's markdown had that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To load router dependencies, add router as a dependency to the test files

I think all the tests in the second file should run automatically.  If it doesn't, there may be something stopping the test.  Are there any async tests?

I have an old blog that has some code regarding qunit and require js that could be of help.  http://naheece.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/qunit-acceptance-test-framework-with-iframe-require-js-and-jquery-simulate/